# continuous second order derivative

Tags: derivatives

I came across an article where a funtion for the price p(z) is referred to as having continuous second derivatives. What implications does this have? Or what information is to be derived from this fact?

Comment: One very frequently-used consequence of this assumption is that second-order partial derivatives are independent of the order they're taken.

Comment: If you link the article, someone might be able to point out where the assumption is needed.

Comment: It says so in Rosen 1974 http://www.stern.nyu.edu/networks/phdcourse/Rosen_Hedonic_prices.pdf on page 4